# Custom annotation from others annotations in java

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, java-annotations, localdatetime

I have date in json like:

```
{
   "date": "04/22/2022 16:01:01" 
}
```

and the class:

```
public class Foo{
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

where everything work fine.

It is posible to have annotation with `@JsonDeserialize` and `@JsonFormat` in it?

I was trying something like this

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
public @interface MyLocalDateTimeAnnotation{
}
```

Where class coud look like this:

```
public class Foo{
    @MyLocalDateTimeAnnotation
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [@JacksonAnnotationsInside](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonAnnotationsInside.html)

> Meta-annotation (annotations used on other annotations) used for
> indicating that instead of using target annotation (annotation
> annotated with this annotation), Jackson should use meta-annotations
> it has. This can be useful in creating "combo-annotations" by having a
> container annotation, which needs to be annotated with this annotation
> as well as all annotations it 'contains'.

Example:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
public @interface MyLocalDateTimeAnnotation {
}

public class Foo{
    @MyLocalDateTimeAnnotation
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```